# Not receiving emails from "Send email action in flows"

Tags: flow-screen-component

I am volunteering at a community site, for which I have created a customer service site with digital experience in my developer's org/ developers edition (URL is:  https://gopioorg-dev-ed.my.site.com/gopioct/s/  ); now I want to send emails through flow action (when I run or debug the flow; emails are sent ) but emails are not being received in the recipient's email address when the flow is called from the active site. Please guide me.

I have tried the following settings but still not working:

1:  verified email address from "Organization-Wide Email Addresses"

2:  set Access level=All emails in "Deliverability"

3 :  site builder >settings > general > guest user profile > clicked on profile link and then went to profile settings > General User Permissions > checked "send email"

Please guide me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the flow action used to send the email ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your flow into [Enabled Flow Access] on Profile Detail

[image: Enabled Flow Access]